# populating tableview datasource inside init method from remote server

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, objective-c-blocks

I have a tabBarView which have two `tableViews`. each of these `tableViews` will represent some news from a remote server. I want to populate `tableView's` datasource when `tableViewController's` `init` method is called. so I have put the needed networking operation inside `init` method. My `init` method is this:

```
- (instancetype) init{
    self = [super init];

    [NewsManager fetch:10 remoteNewsOfLanguage:@"fa" withOffsett:1 andCompletionHandler:^(NSMutableArray *news) {
        self.newsList = news;
    }];

    self.tabBarItem.title = @"my title";


    return self;
}
```

newsList is an array holding news loaded from server.

But when I run my project the order of invocation for `tableViewController's` methods is like the following:

- `tableViewController's init` method is called and finished (but the completion handler block is not called yet)
- `tableViewController's` `viewDidLoad` method is called ( it is called when the `tableViewController` is added to `tabBarView's` `viewControllers` array)
- `tableViewController's` delegate method `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection` is called
- the network operation's `completionHandler` block is called and the newsList array is set to the retrieved news from server

So my problem is that before my newsList array is populated the method `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection` is called and so my `tableView` is not filled with any news. How should I solve this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should reload table data after you get data from server. then only your table will show updated data.

```
[NewsManager fetch:10 remoteNewsOfLanguage:@"fa" withOffsett:1 andCompletionHandler:^(NSMutableArray *news) {
    self.newsList = news;
   [yourTableview reloadData];//add this line
}];
```

The added line does the job and makes the new data to be loaded in the tableView but there is a small point that I think you should consider

```
  [tableView reloadData]
```

will be executed in a thread other than mainThread and this will cause a 5 to 10 seconds delay for the data to be loaded on the tableView.
to prevent this you should somehow tell it to run the reloadData method on the main thread. this is done with the **dispatch_async**. So you should call [tableView reloadData] like this:

```
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.tableView reloadData];
  });
```